# Google spreadsheet countif non empty cells except certain values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So basically i want to check if certain range of field is not blank or has a certain value

so

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(NOT(ISBLANK(H24:I28)), true))`

will count if they are blank

How can i edit it to also search for a certain value so far i've tried :

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(NOT(ISBLANK(H24:I28)) OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("someValue",H24:I28,1)>0,FALSE)), true))
```

Here is a link to a sheet as an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sc8xmLf8_EYFoQb3kNQRdxdd-9PemrJ4lDhTfIqCJNg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just saw your sheet. You mention "Members count: 4" Which ones do you count? `Canada, French, Palma, US`? If so, what is the meaning of `Empty 1`, `Empty 2`? Please explain.

Comment: You say "i want to check if certain range of field is not blank or has a certain value", but it is effectually the same as "i want to check if certain range of field is not blank" as having a certain value means it is not blank, thus making logical expression true. Maybe you want to count something else?

Comment: Well i want to count every value except anything that starts with the word Empty basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update following OP's details:

> Well i want to count every value except anything that starts with the word Empty basically

```
=COUNTIF(H24:I29,"<>") - 
 COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(H24:I29,"Empty")),TRUE)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

---

#### Initial answer

To find **whether `theValue` exists or not**, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H24:I28,"<>")>0,IF(COUNTIF(H24:I28,"someValue")>0,"someValue","no value"),"empty")
```

To **count how many times `theValue` exists**, please use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H24:I28,"<>")>0,IF(COUNTIF(H24:I28,"someValue")>0,COUNTIF(H24:I28,"someValue"),"no value"),"empty")
```

---

*(Of course you can adjust the "messages" to your liking)*

Functions used:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Please check the updated formula following your latest explanation _"...count every value except anything that starts with the word Empty"_

Comment: I would also suggest 2 edits to your original question so as to  make it more user friendly. **1. You could change the title** to something like: _"Countif non empty cells except certain values"_. **2. Include your final request into your question** instead of it being just a comment.

Comment: Please keep in mind that it is _"Google Spreadsheets"_ and not *"stylespread sheet"*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `OR()` operator:

**Example:**

> `=ArrayFormula(OR(COUNTIF(NOT(ISBLANK(H24:I28)),true),IFERROR(SEARCH("someValue",H24:I28,1)>0,FALSE)))`

---

**References:**
- [`OR()` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)

Comment: In your question what you have tried, you are not using ´OR()´ correctly.